# How to understand the method 'isPlaintext' in HttpLoggingInterceptor.class?

Tags: java, okhttp

I am confused how the `Human Readable Text` is defined. I guess since Unicode contains almost all the language characters, then as long as the codePoint is in it, it is readable.

But in [HttpLoggingInterceptor # isPlaintext(buffer)](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_3.14.x/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.java#L301):

```
static boolean isPlaintext(Buffer buffer) {
        try {
            Buffer prefix = new Buffer();
            long byteCount = buffer.size() < 64 ? buffer.size() : 64;
            buffer.copyTo(prefix, 0, byteCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                if (prefix.exhausted()) {
                    break;
                }
                int codePoint = prefix.readUtf8CodePoint();
                if (Character.isISOControl(codePoint) && !Character.isWhitespace(codePoint)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            return false; // Truncated UTF-8 sequence.
        }
    }
```

It shows that bytes are not readable if they contain non-whiteSpace control characters.

What is the reason for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAI could see `readUtf8CodePoint` returns UTF-8 codepoint for given buffer.

From Wikipedia

> UTF-8 is a variable width character encoding capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid code points in Unicode using one to four 8-bit bytes.

So Unicode does not necessarily covers only human readable charachters. So UTF-8 range has control charachters as well with unicode `\u0000` through `\u001F` or in the range `\u007F` through `\u009F` and these are not human readable.

Remember Unicode is standard and UTF-8 is one of way to encode Unicode.

Comment: You are right. Is it possible to conclude that `ALL` control characters other than the above are readable?

Comment: No control character is readable. They represent non-printable set of chars like bell, backspace, tab, form-feed etc.

Comment: Sorry for my imprecision. I know control characters are not printable, I mean whether a string containing control characters other than the one mentioned above (00~1F, 7F~9F) is considered plain text or not. Such as `RLO`, it just controls the direction of text, so `isPlaintext` returns true for a string containing `RLO`. Not like the U+00.